# NSMutableArray. Object value is not being replaced

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a `NSMutableArray` and I want to change the value of a particular object.

However, it's not changing.

Below is my code:

```
//create two array to store data later
NSMutableArray *feelingsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


// get paths from root direcory

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

// get documents path

NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// get the path to our Data/plist file

NSString *feelingsPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Feeling.plist"];



//This copies objects of plist to array if there is one
[feelingsArray addObjectsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:feelingsPath]];

//replace object at particular location
[datesArray replaceObjectAtIndex:number withObject:feeling.text];
```

Do I need to make any changes or add some code like synchronise etc.?

Please provide some guidance.

Comment: What does the feelingsArray have to do with the replace? Why is that code included? The replace only uses datesArray, number and feeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
[datesArray replaceObjectAtIndex:number withObject:feeling.text];
```

be

```
[feelingsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:number withObject:feeling.text];
```

?

Comment: I see you're new to this site. Welcome! If someone posts an answer that resolves your issue, then you should accept that answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left. If you never accept any answers, then people will start ignoring your questions.